# Constructor Arguments ABI-encoded - verification not working!

Tags: tokens, contract-debugging, etherscan

I think I must be going blind or something because I can not find the Constructor Arguments for this smart contract 0x3a2F46b0B0c187B152Db0c658b27E693f0A273a1

I have tried a number of options but always fails the https://etherscan.io/verifyContract?a=0x3a2f46b0b0c187b152db0c658b27e693f0a273a1

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Can you share your code? Gist maybe.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply, here is the smart contract: https://github.com/Bunzola/Bunzola/blob/master/contracts/BunzolaToken.sol

Answer (score 0):

The code is using .16 version (which was last launched in Aug'17) and the code has been updated 5 days ago. The deployed code at 0x3a2f46b0b0c187b152db0c658b27e693f0a273a1 and the github code is not matching while verifying.

The constructor is `BunzolaToken` function, however it's not asking for any arguments.